# Mongoose : query if array has length > 0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

#### Note:

> *I have tried all the solutions on other questions and most of them are outdated*

I need to query projects who's number of requesters are greater than 0, to make an endpoint to fetch notifications.

> Model :

```
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 300, maxlength: 3000 },
  comments: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Comment'
  }],
  state: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  requesters: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Profile'
  }]
}
```

This is the query I have tried and it doesn't seem to work.
It is returning a blank array for some reason.

```js
const projects = await Project.find({
    user: req.currentUser!.id,
    "requestersLength": { "$gt": 0 }
  });
  res.send(projects);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "outdated" ? Nothing changed in array length calculation since first mongodb release.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/

Answer (score 0):

**Query for Finding all documents in the array  that have at least one element.**

```
db.CollectionName.find({'arrayFiled.0': {$exists: true}})
```

In your case your code will be look like this

```
const projects = await Project.find({
    user: req.currentUser!.id,
    {'requesters.0': {$exists: true}}
  });
  res.send(projects);
```

**Also You can use `$expr` Query Operator (*New in version 3.6.+*)**

> Which allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query
> language.
>
> ```
> { $expr: { <expression> } }
> ```

**Example**:

```
 db.CollectionName.find({$expr:{$gt:[{$size:"$yourArrayField"}, 0]}})
```

Read more about `$expr` [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)